# Proper use of std::string to send binary data through a socket

Tags: c++, sockets, c++11, network-programming

I'm trying to send files splitted in chunks over a TCP Berkley Socket but i'm getting unexpected behaviors.

```
std::ifstream inFile (path.c_str(),std::ios::in|std::ios::binary|std::ios::ate); 
std::streampos _size;
_size = inFile.tellg();
char * _buffer = new char [MAXLINE];
int    _chunk = 0;
inFile.seekg (0, std::ios::beg);

msg << "ACK" << " " << "START" << " " << message[1];
connTSock->send_message(msg.str());

while(inFile.read(_buffer , MAXLINE))
{
   CLEAR_MSG(msg);
   msg << "ACK" << " " << "CHUNK" << " " << _chunk << " " << _buffer;
   _chunk++;
   connTSock->send_message(msg.str());
}
```

In few words I am getting a loss of data , the client opens an output stream and writes in it , but i.e. of 11 kb of the original file i get only 7kb on the other side. I guess that the problem could be related to the fact that I'm pushing the _buffer in a std::stringstream and then converting it in a std::string. 
Am I right? How could I fix this problem?

Comment: Is your data formatted as a string, as in a null-terminated buffer of characters?  Or is it arbitrary binary data?

Comment: What is `connTSock`?

Comment: Because `_buffer` is a `char*` - which lacks its own notion of how many characters from that address are relevant, `msg << ... _buffer` will append only the text until a NUL/`\0` character is found.  That could cause data loss.  Another common problem is when receiving data over TCP: you should not expect any particular amount of data from a single `read`/`recv` - it is not tied to the peer's `write`/`send`s.  You must loop until you explicitly hit EOF.  More explicitly, doing say 1 `recv` per chunk `sent` is very likely to fail, especially under network load.

Comment: @Yakk i need to handle both types

Comment: @juanchopanza it's a class that inherits from a tcp socket class

Comment: `msg << "ACK" << " " << "CHUNK" << " " << _chunk << " " << _buffer;` can clearly not encoded embedded `'\0'`s into `msg`, as it takes `_buffer` as a pointer to the first element.

Comment: @Yakk ok i understand but how can i fix this problem ?

Comment: @GiorgioGambino: Your messages need to specify the actual number of chunk bytes being sent, and then you need to actually send that many bytes. Your `msg` values are not doing that. Try something more like this instead: `while(inFile.read(_buffer, MAXLINE)) { std::streamsize _buflen = inFile.gcount(); ... msg << "ACK CHUNK " << _chunk << " " << _buflen << " " << std::string(_buffer, _buflen); ... }`

Comment: @GiorgioGambino: Or: `while(inFile.read(_buffer, MAXLINE)) { std::streamsize _buflen = inFile.gcount(); ... (msg << "ACK CHUNK " << _chunk << " " << _buflen << " ").write(_buffer, _buflen); ... }`